"extension-apiserver-authentication": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again
When I tried to use this command to restore some configmap to kubernetes cluster:
kubectl --kubeconfig=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.kube/admin.conf apply -f reddwarf-configmap.yaml -v=9

the kubernetes shows error like this:
I0706 17:09:37.240772   37443 request.go:1181] Request Body: {"metadata":{"resourceVersion":"18"}}
I0706 17:09:37.240835   37443 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XPATCH  -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/strategic-merge-patch+json" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.23.0 (darwin/arm64) kubernetes/ab69524" 'https://120.27.115.168:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/extension-apiserver-authentication?fieldManager=kubectl-client-side-apply'
I0706 17:09:37.292991   37443 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: GetConnection 0 ms ServerProcessing 51 ms Duration 52 ms
I0706 17:09:37.293034   37443 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
I0706 17:09:37.293051   37443 round_trippers.go:580]     X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid: 1c6d7eea-ebb7-41af-931f-526131a91b7c
I0706 17:09:37.293066   37443 round_trippers.go:580]     Content-Length: 364
I0706 17:09:37.293078   37443 round_trippers.go:580]     Date: Sat, 06 Jul 2024 09:09:37 GMT
I0706 17:09:37.293091   37443 round_trippers.go:580]     Audit-Id: 4c2ce91b-bf02-4144-9044-9602301c0131
I0706 17:09:37.293104   37443 round_trippers.go:580]     Cache-Control: no-cache, private
I0706 17:09:37.293117   37443 round_trippers.go:580]     Content-Type: application/json
I0706 17:09:37.293130   37443 round_trippers.go:580]     X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid: eadf225e-0210-40b2-9023-9f2f862b1f89
I0706 17:09:37.293409   37443 request.go:1181] Response Body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Operation cannot be fulfilled on configmaps \"extension-apiserver-authentication\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again","reason":"Conflict","details":{"name":"extension-apiserver-authentication","kind":"configmaps"},"code":409}

I can use the kubectl to get the cluster pod info, why could not apply the configmap?
kubectl --kubeconfig=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.kube/admin.conf get pods

NAME                                      READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
nfs-client-provisioner-5b88b85974-6w5r4   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          42h
traefik-688d4485c4-kfxxb                  0/1     ContainerCreating   0          42h

By the way, I already apply the pv\pvc\depployement\service. But facing issue when deploy the configmap. what should I do to fixed this issue?
